# append object instance to a list with a if statement and print it in another branch

Tags: python, list, variables

I create a few class about pet, the following code was part of my main() function, First, ask the user to select one thing they want to do. that is if use input '1' they will add some pet instance. At the same time, I want to append part of the pet instance's information to a list. Then if the user chooses to read this information. I want to print it in another if statement branch. that is when the user input '2'. the problem occurs when I input 2 after already generating some pet instance. the list called l_weight always be void. How could I fix it?  I already try to use the global list but is not work

```
def main():
l_weight=[]
print("========menu=========")
print("1. to add a pet")
print("2. print current weight for all pet")
print("3. print all pets and owners")
print("4. to exist system")
a=int(input("you selection(just input the number before each function)"))
while(True):
    if a==1: 
        a=int(input("please select what type of pet would be added: 1-- mammals 2--fish 3--amphibians"))
        name = input('please enter the  name of pet:')
        dob = input('please enter the dob of pet:(year,month,day)')
        bw = input('please enter the birth weight:')
        name = input('please enter the owner name:')
        address = input('please enter the onwer address:')
        if a==1:
            ls = input('please enter the litter size:')
            hs = input('pet has claws(yes or no):')
            op=mammals(name,dob,bw,name,address,ls,hs)
            print(op)
            l_weight.append(op.get_current_weight)      
        elif a==2:
            sc = input('please enter the scale condition:')
            sl = input('please enter the scale length:')
            op =fish(name,dob,bw,name,address,sc,sl)
            print(op)
            l_weight.append(op.get_current_weight)
        elif a==3:
            iv = input('is venomous(yes or no):')
            op =amphibians(name,dob,bw,name,address,iv)
            print(op)
            l_weight.append(op.get_current_weight)
        else:
            print(' input wrong vaule,please choose a number from 1,2 or 3')
        return main()
    elif a==2:  
        for i in l_weight:
            print(i)
        
        return main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason l_weight() isn't appending is because in your code, you named the list `l_weight` and then in the rest of your code it's written as `l_weigh`

It should be:

```
def main():
  l_weight=[]

  print("========menu=========")
  print("1. to add a pet")
  print("2. print current weight for all pet")
  print("3. print all pets and owners")
  print("4. to exist system")
  a=int(input("you selection(just input the number before each function)"))

  while(True):
      if a==1: 
          a=int(input("please select what type of pet would be added: 1-- mammals 2--fish 3--amphibians"))
          name = input('please enter the  name of pet:')
          dob = input('please enter the dob of pet:(year,month,day)')
          bw = input('please enter the birth weight:')
          name = input('please enter the owner name:')
          address = input('please enter the onwer address:')

          if a==1:
              ls = input('please enter the litter size:')
              hs = input('pet has claws(yes or no):')
              op=mammals(name,dob,bw,name,address,ls,hs)
              print(op)
              l_weight.append(op.get_current_weight)      
          elif a==2:
              sc = input('please enter the scale condition:')
              sl = input('please enter the scale length:')
              op =fish(name,dob,bw,name,address,sc,sl)
              print(op)
              l_weight.append(op.get_current_weight)
          elif a==3:
              iv = input('is venomous(yes or no):')
              op =amphibians(name,dob,bw,name,address,iv)
              print(op)
              l_weight.append(op.get_current_weight)
          else:
              print(' input wrong vaule,please choose a number from 1,2 or 3')
      elif a==2:  
          for i in l_weight:
              print(i)
```

Comment: thank you, I correct it. but it still not work. I think the l_weight list would be clear every time after user input.  I want to repeat running the main function until the user wants to exit the system, so after each if statement It will return main()

Comment: No problem! include the menu portion into the while loop and you can do this. Of course you have to create the condition to check if the user enters in 4 to exit. Right now you're only checking the menu options 1 and 2